# Extracting indexes from a max pool over uniform data

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to find max points in a 2D tensor for a given kernel size, but I'm having issues with a special case where all the values are uniform. For example, given the following example, I would like to mark each point as a max point:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

If I run torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d with a kernel size=3, stride=1, and padding=1, I get the following indicies:

```
+---+---+---+----+
| 0 | 0 | 1 |  2 |
+---+---+---+----+
| 0 | 0 | 1 |  2 |
+---+---+---+----+
| 4 | 4 | 5 |  6 |
+---+---+---+----+
| 8 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

What changes do I need to account for to instead obtain the following indicies?

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  |  4 |
+----+----+----+----+
|  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |
+----+----+----+----+
|  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
+----+----+----+----+
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: That is a good question! Looks like standard `MaxPool` from multiple the best choices returns that it scaned first. It would be better to choose closest to the middle of kernel region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
a = torch.ones(4,4)
indices = (a == torch.max(a).item()).nonzero()
```

What this does is return a `[16,2]` sized tensor with the 2D coordinates of the max value(s), i.e. `[0,0], [0,1], .., [3,3]`. The `torch.max` part should be easy to understand, `nonzero()` considers the boolean tensor given by `(a == torch.max(a).item())`, takes `False` to be 0, and returns the non-zero indices. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this gives the requested output in this specific case, but not in the max case; however, it was able to push me to the right solution. Knowing nonzero() is useful. 

To generalize this, you'd use max pool on an input, then subtract the activation (i.e. maxpool output) from the input, then use this technique but for cells which are equal to 0 (kind of the opposite of nonzero()).

Answer (score 0):

If you want indices in `2d` shape @ccl have give you answer but for `1d` indices you can first make `x` 1d using [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.flatten) tensor and then get indices with [`torch.nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.nonzero) and finally convert into same shape.

```py
x = torch.ones(4,4) * 5

(x.flatten() == x.flatten().max()).nonzero().reshape(x.shape) + 1
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```